# facing navigation issue due to scanning sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, camera

I integrated third party scanning sdk in my iPhone application. My application is navigationbased and while integrating the third party scanning sdk navigation is breaked because the first file of sdk is scannigSDKTestViewController.mm which can be initialized by using the initWithCoder method only.

I am calling scannigSDKTestViewController from viewControllerX as below.

```
//in viewControllerX.h file
scannigSDKTestViewController *overlayController;

//in viewControllerX.m file 
    -(void) start_Scanning
    {

    [AppDelegate setNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    overlayController = [[scannigSDKTestViewController alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
        }
        else {
            [overlayController release];
            overlayController = nil;

            overlayController = [[scanningSDKTestViewController alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
        }

        [self.view addSubview:overlayController.view];
        [overlayController startScanning];
    }
```

//navigationController is declared in applicationnameAppDelegate.h file

in scanningSDKTestViewController.mm file ,I am calling the other viewController ViewControllerZ as below code

```
UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [AppDelegate navigationController];

ViewControllerZ *viewScreenZ = [[ViewControllerZ alloc] init];
[myNavigationController pushViewController:viewScreenZ animated:NO];
[viewScreenZ release];
[myNavigationController release];
```

In the above approach camera is opening and scanning is happing ,but after some scanning the application is crashing.And I think the crash is happening due to UINavigationController handle `myNavigationController`,but without taking this handle after scanning navigation to any other screen is stopped.
I have no ideas how to solve this navigation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show next views by using `presentModalViewController` method, as below code.

```
ViewControllerZ *viewScreenZ = [[ViewControllerZ alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewScreenZ animated:YES]; 
[viewScreenZ release];
```